# Modeling Experimental data with a CDF

Tags: distributions, modeling

[image]

I have some data plotted above which relates two variables that were derived experimentally. I'm trying to fit a cumulative distribution function to it so that we can take a sample of Y at X. I've been looking at the raw data (found at the bottom of this post) and my question is how to best probabilistically model this relationship.

I can fit a model to it easily (below). Roughly the results are $x^5$.

[image]

Taking the last value of each run, when I try a SmoothKernalDistribution however, the results don't look like the data at all.

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data[[All, -1, 2]] // Flatten];
Plot[CDF[dist, x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Raw Data:

```
{{{0., 0.}, {0.52, 0.}, {0.8, 0.3}, {0.9, 0.56}, {0.95, 0.75}, {0.98, 0.89}, {0.98, 0.91}, {0.99, 0.96}, {1., 0.97}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.69,0.}, {0.81, 0.44}, {0.89, 0.65}, {0.96, 0.82}, {0.98, 0.88}, {0.99,0.96}, {1., 0.98}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.47, 0.}, {0.79, 0.26}, {0.88,0.53}, {0.96, 0.75}, {0.99, 0.85}, {0.99, 0.96}, {1., 0.98}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.58, 0.}, {0.79, 0.26}, {0.89, 0.59}, {0.96, 0.79}, {0.97, 0.85}, {1., 0.91}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.59, 0.}, {0.79, 0.35}, {0.88, 0.56}, {0.95, 0.77}, {0.97, 0.89}, {0.98, 0.91}, {0.99, 0.94}, {0.99, 0.96}, {1., 0.99}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.59, 0.}, {0.82, 0.34}, {0.96, 0.63}, {0.97, 0.79}, {0.99, 0.86}, {1., 0.93}},
{{0.,0.}, {0.54, 0.}, {0.79, 0.26}, {0.91, 0.57}, {0.98, 0.76}, {0.99, 0.84}, {1., 0.96}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.75, 0.22}, {0.86, 0.48}, {0.95, 0.76}, {0.98, 0.88}, {0.98, 0.95}, {1., 0.97}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.55, 0.}, {0.8, 0.3}, {0.95, 0.65}, {0.99, 0.78}, {1., 0.89}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.63, 0.}, {0.84, 0.34}, {0.9, 0.68}, {0.95, 0.79}, {0.98, 0.87}, {0.99, 0.91}, {1., 0.95}}}
```

Comment: If memory serves the ``SmoothKernelDistribution`` assumes the data describe the PDF, not the CDF, so you're fitting for the former but expecting the get the latter ;-)

Comment: How is the response variable derived? Is it the number of successes out of 100? Is it a fraction because it is a real-valued proportion of some amount (say percent weight)? What are the 10 different sets of (x,y) pairs?  Are these 10 independent replications? Your information given in the question makes me wonder if this is not a sample from a probability distribution but just a regression problem with a form that happens to have the same shape as a cumulative probability distribution function.

Comment: For 4 of the 10 series a "time step" is duplicated at either .98 (series 1 and 8) or .99 (series 3 or 5). What's going on there?